# Proper Spanish translation for "chief" in expressions like "chief designer"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, españa, adjetivos

There is a dialog in *Love Actually* that goes like this:

> **Harry**: Tell me, exactly, how long it is that you've been working here?
>   **Sarah**: Two years, seven months, three days and, I suppose, what... two hours?
>   **Harry**: And how long have you been in love with Karl, our enigmatic chief designer?
>   **Sarah**: Ahm, two years, seven months, three days and, I suppose, an hour and thirty minutes.

In the European Spanish version of the movie, Karl is mentioned to be the "primer diseñador". Now, "primer diseñador" is indeed a good translation. If we see the definitions for both words, we have:

> [Chief](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chief) - accorded **highest rank** or office.
>   [Primer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UAztjAx) - dicho de una persona o de una cosa: **que precede a las demás de su especie en** orden, tiempo, lugar, situación, clase o **jerarquía**.

What bothers me is that *chief* is the person with "the highest rank", but *primer* (or *primero*) can be the first not only in rank, but in many other things (order, time, place and so on). So a "primer diseñador" could be understood as the first one that was hired by the company (the first in time).

So, what other adjectives can be used to say that someone is the first in rank in a more straightforward, unmistakable way? Maybe "diseñador [jefe](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MPAoQ4z)"? "Diseñador [principal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UBnRzW7)"? What is the adjective that is more commonly used in Spanish by companies when they want to hire a "chief something"?

Comment: Jefe de diseño. Chief engineer: Jefe de ingeniería, etc.

Comment: Diseñador jefe sería una buena opción si se hace el paralelo con, digamos, [Redactor jefe](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redactor_jefe)

Comment: Linguée me dió "Actualmente llamamos a esto tecnología catapulta", declaró Bill Jacobs, ingeniero jefe del proyecto MagLev en el Marshall Space Flight Center [...]" y me gusta.  También se me ocurre "jefe de diseño".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este tipo de jerarquías, *chief* se suele traducir como **director** o **directora**:

> [**director, ra**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=director)
>
> 2. m. y f. Persona que dirige algo en razón de su profesión o de su cargo. El director de la empresa, de la investigación. Es directora de cine.
>
> **director, ra artístico, ca**
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona que decide la orientación artística y la programación de un teatro, de un festival, etc.
>
> **director, ra de escena**
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona que se ocupa de la dirección de todo lo relativo a la representación de una obra teatral, como la interpretación, la ambientación, etc.

Usado en el mismo sentido que en expresiones como "directora artística" o "director de escena", tenemos:

- [***Chief*** executive officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_executive_officer) -> [**Director** ejecutivo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_ejecutivo)
- [***Chief*** technology officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_technology_officer) -> [**Director** de tecnología](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_de_tecnolog%C3%ADa)
- [***Chief*** commercial officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_commercial_officer) -> [**Director** comercial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_comercial)

No hay versión española del artículo para [*Chief Design Officer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_design_officer), que viene a ser el equivalente de *chief designer*, pero de lo anterior se sigue que en español se le podría llamar **director de diseño**.

Otra opción un poco menos "corporativa" sería, como apunta Gustavson en los comentarios (y tú mismo en la pregunta, según acabo de darme cuenta), **jefe/a de diseño** o **diseñador/a jefe**, aunque (sorprendentemente) las acepciones que da el DLE tienen un sentido más absoluto del que buscamos:

> **[jefe, fa](http://dle.rae.es/?w=jefe)**
>   <sub>Del fr. *chef*.
>
>   Para el f., u. t. la forma *jefe* en acep. 1</sub>
>
> 1. m. y f. Superior o cabeza de una corporación, partido u oficio.

A pesar de que, etimológicamente hablando, es la palabra que más cerca estaría de *chief* (ambas vienen del francés *chef*).

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, ¿cómo fue la evolución de _chef_ a _jefe_? ¿Pasó la evolución por _chefe_ o por _jef_?

Comment: @walen En realidad, es la combinación de "chief" + "officer" que da por resultado "director" (funcionario principal de X área). Si no está "officer", se entiende que se trata de un cargo de menor jerarquía, aunque sea el de máximo nivel dentro de un área específica. Si no, serían todos directores. Trabajé en empresas toda mi vida, y me cansé de oír "jefe de ingeniería", "jefe de geología", etc. etc., todos ellos seguramente reportando a un Director Técnico, por ejemplo. No te confundas con el coloquial "el jefe".

Comment: Para mi "jefe de"  seria mas "Head of" mientras que como dices "Chief" lo traduciria como "Director"